# HTML5 multiple video from one source loading

Tags: html

I'm trying to add multiple (3) video with same source, but they load multiple times. Do you have any idea how if the source is the same they do not load 3 times?

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
    display: none;
}
```

```
<video width="285" autoplay playsinline muted loop>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<video width="285" autoplay playsinline muted loop>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<video width="285" autoplay playsinline muted loop>
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

[Chrome Network media](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQmX4.png)

Comment: How long is the video?

Comment: This is example video, but the real video is 13 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn't load the same video multiple times. I only loaded that video once on Safari, but according to Web Inspector, it loads different sections of the video to reduce the load on your computers memory. For example if you are watching a movie, it doesn't want to load all 2 hours of that 1080p movie onto RAM, so it loads sections of it.

[image: image of byte ranges]

Comment: Okay, for Chrome I can assume it doesn't load 3 times, but for Firefox https://i.imgur.com/L5sodJk.png